# wsl executes only bash commands and not windows options

Tags: cmd, command-line, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to execute cmd commands such as `wsl -l`, wsl returns this message:

`/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument`

However, using `wsl` as a bash command launcher works.

What do I have to do in order to use wsl windows options such as `wsl -l`, `wsl --install`, etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you've entered `wsl` command in the Linux terminal and when you did this the first time bash answered you that the command was not found , so you installed  'wsl' package. This is a completely different package.  If you want to invoke Windows binaries from bash you should use .exe file extension. Try `wsl.exe -l`